# How to assign a dictionary a name attribute

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I am trying to assign a dictionary a name attribute, so I can call that attribute inside functions. What are ways that a dictionary can be assigned a .name attribute?

When I create a dictionary from a dataframe using the to_dict method, those dictionaries have a .name attribute. I can use this .name attribute inside of a function. If the dictionary is not from a dataframe but created with dict(zip), the dictionary doesn't have a name and I don't know how to go about assigning one.

```
def function(dict1,dict2):
    plt.scatter(dict1['A'],dict2['A'])
    plt.title(dict1.name)
    plt.show()
```

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'

If the dictionary was created with to_dict, I do not get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary uses keys and values. You can define a 'name' key and then set the value associated with that 'name' key. For example:

```
dic = {}
dic["name"] = "My name"
```

In order to access the value use dic["name"]

```
# Prints "My Name"
print(dic["name"])
```

Comment: I'm not talking about assigning a key to a value, I'm talking about having dict.name = 'Dictionary Name'

Comment: You can't. Python dictionaries work only the way I outlined above.